# Center align wrapped content with with display: inline-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an inline-block menu (made with bootstrap 3) and I want to know if it's possible to center align any content that wraps?

Here's a codepen highlighting the issue

http://codepen.io/Kathrynwatts/pen/VebjzW

As you can see, when you downsize the screen, all the list items align to the left (which is default wrapping behavior). I'd like them to wrap to the center, if I can.

[image: Nav items align to left edge]

CSS

```
.plays-nav { //parent container
font-weight: 400;
letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.plays-nav>li { //menu list items
text-align: center;
}

.navbar-centered .navbar-nav { //parent container
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-centered .navbar-nav > li { //menu list items
    float: none;
}

.navbar-centered .nav > li { //menu list items
    display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you `text-align:center` *the parent*, `display:inline-block` *children* will stack in the middle and wrap. Subsequent rows will also be center aligned. So this will do it:

```
.plays-nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Note: When using this solution make sure the `left` and `right` paddings on the parent are equal and no `float`s are set on children.

Answer (score 2):

change the code comment `//parent container` to `/* parent container */`.
Your code is correct, but the comment format is wrong,  CSS comments must be the formatted as `/* comment content*/`, otherwise the code after your comment might be affected.

Comment: While true and useful, your answer does not address the question being asked. I guess it would have been better to post it as comment to the question. +1-ed anyway, for helpful intention.

Comment: thank you ,my English is poor, I can't completely understand the meaning of the question. but I'm afraid asker going to make mistakes for this reason.

Comment: I added the comments just for the question, so you guys would know what the classes symbolized. Thanks for the tip though :)